# FBJS Ajax to load content

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, fbml, fbjs

I tried one of the examples [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS/Examples/Ajax) to load the content in the div, but apart from displaying the image, it doesn't show anything. Where I'm going wrong?

File `ajax1.js`:

```
function General_Refresh(url,div){
    //Showing the load image (pay attention to /> of <img
    document.getElementById(div).setInnerXHTML('<span id="caric"><center><img src="http://website.name/images/ajax-loader.gif" /></center></span>');
    var ajax = new Ajax();
    ajax.responseType = Ajax.FBML;

    ajax.ondone = function(data) {
        //Hide the loading image
        document.getElementById('caric').setStyle('display','none');
        document.getElementById(div).setInnerFBML(data);
    }
    //If there are errors re-try
    ajax.onerror = function() {
        General_Refresh(url,div);
    }
    ajax.post(url);
}
```

File `quote.html`:

```
    <script src="http://website.name/scripts/ajax1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        General_Refresh("http://website.name/quote.php","quote");
        //-->
    </script>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="quote"><strong>this</strong></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: one thing i tried is that if i call the general_refresh function in the js file itself, the image will continue to show. but if i put it in the html file like how it is done above, it loads once and then disappears. neither is any content loaded. the app is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with FBJS/Ajax. It was an error in `quote.php`.